# I need to understand what Netbeans does when I press the play button

Tags: java, netbeans

I have been programming in Java for many years, every now and then, but at a totally amateur level, just small utilities for myself. My problem is that I used Netbeans since day one, and I have zero knowledge about the process of building projects and the like.

I would like to solve this limitation that I have. I would like to know what Netbeans does when I press the "play" button. But basic books talk about variables, loops ... I already know all that. I am looking for books or other resources focused on the building process, not on the language.

(the close motivation for this question is that I tried to program a JavaFX application and I found myself lost in the files tree that Netbeans generates ... but I look for a general understanding, not only to solve this particular problem)

I read basic Java books and Netbeans books. I didn't find the information I look for.

Comment: Your IDE compiles your program into bytecode and .class files. Which folder structure is used depends on the project settings or whether you use e.g. maven (which standardizes the folder structure). Your IDE usually does not generate a .jar file from the .class files.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I want to learn about. I am happy my question is understandable, becausee I had doubts. Now I would like a whole book about those processes :-)

Comment: If you really want to know the steps, take a look at the build.xml file or the file that the embedded Netbeans Ant program does, it will contain all the steps to build the program and run it.

Comment: NetBeans look for a class that has the main method.  If there's multiple classes with main method, it will ask you which class to run.  But you should learn to code using just a text editor and the shell.  It's just java Classname.class.

Comment: If somebody writes an answer saying "the book or resources that you are looking for don't exist", I will accetp that answer.